# Which sentences are normal in a commercial company user end license agreement?

Tags: licensing

I was reading an 'User End License Agreement' and asked myself whether such paragraphs aren't suspect. As well my I asked myself whether such sentences are normal in those end license agreements or are verbalized in other form.

> You agree to create, retain and provide to Axosoft and its auditors accurate written records and other system information sufficient to provide auditable verification that Your use of all Software is in compliance with this Agreement, including without limitation, that Your use does not exceed the number of copies of the Software for which You are licensed.  Upon reasonable notice, Axosoft may verify your compliance with the Agreement at all sites and for all environments in which You use the Software.  Such verification will be conducted in a manner that minimizes disruption to Your business, and may be conducted on Your premises, during normal business hours.  Axosoft may use an independent auditor to assist with such verification, provided Axosoft has a written confidentiality agreement in place with such auditor.    Axosoft will notify You in writing if any such verification indicates that You have used any Software in excess of Your use rights or otherwise not in compliance with this Agreement.

(From gitkraken)

As I understood this software is monitoring my activity accurate all the time. Isn't that quite hysteric? *[Thanks for all corrections!]*

Comment: If your company is big enough that the software vendor is interested on whether  you are over using your software licenses, then you will also be big enough to have software license monitoring in place, and be able to report on software license useage easily.

Comment: Do I have be worried about my privacy? That's what I'm thinking about to, I admit :S

Comment: That contract wording does not imply that the software is phoning home on its usage.

Comment: That's the result if people are trying to read the end user license agreements :'D

Comment: If people disklike this question, it would be nice to tell me why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording in that contract is not unusual.

In practice it means that they are asking you to track how many licences you own, who each license is assigned to, and to validate that people are not "sharing" licenses or downloading "cracked" versions off the internet.

If the vendor wanted to do a license audit, it would likely involve first establishing from the paper trail how many licenses you actually own, and then requesting you to identify on which machines are associated with each license.

They would then check a sample of machines without licenses, and as long as no unlicensed installations were found, they would thank you for your time and say good bye.

If you are unable to identify how many licenses you own, or which machines are licensed, then they would be likely to investigate every machine, and then tell you how many licenses you are using, and then send you a large invoice for breach of contract and for any additional licences you were found to be using.

This costs the vendor both money to pay for the audit, and also in customer good will if customers feel they are being unfairly targeted, so software companies generally only perform an audit if they have good reason to suspect widespread license abuse.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a legal expert. The following shall not be considered as legal advice, but only my personal opinion.*

The clause seems quite common.  In [this article about an audit clause time bomb](http://www.scottandscottllp.com/main/ibm_audit_clause.aspx), you can find a critical analysis of a similar text from a known vendor.  The main criticism form the legal expert does however relate only to additional financial provisions in case of non-compliance.

Of course, audit clauses are always a constraint for the customer. But looking at the usual delicate points in [this article on fair audit clauses](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2586628/enterprise-applications/a-fair-audit-clause.html) and [this article on top 3 revision requests of such clauses](http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=f214ef78-8f7c-4ab9-b8be-27e7df0e2f4b), it appears that the wording seems rather moderate and balanced.

**Aditionional remarks:**

I think that the right to "*conduct verifications*" would not necessarily imply that third party could directly manipulate your IT systems without your consent.  You could very well have your own technical staff operating the system verifications under the auditor's oversight.

It also seems to me that compliance with local laws would remain mandatory for everyone in your premises.  This implies that verification tasks couldn't infringe applicable data protection rules.

Finally, the text doesn't state that the software records everything when you use it. And anyway, recording that your use complies with license doesn't mean that big brother is watching you hysterically;  It's just that relevant licensing elements are monitored.  Depending on the contractual terms it could mean the number of copies installed, the number of registered or concurrent users, or the use of some specific functionality subject to extra charges or limitations.

Comment: Okay, that seems all logic to me. But one thing I'm wondering about.  How can I have a license if the software doesn't cost anything?

Comment: A license is a right to use the software under certain conditions. These do not necessarily imply payment. Many popular open source license come free of charge.  But you can also have licenses that are free for personal use and chargeable for professional use. Or free for testing period and chargeable afterwards. Or free for an entry-level product but chargeable for more comprehensive variants.